Wayland broke after updating kernel from 6.5.0~45 to 6.8.0
I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on QEMU and I use Virtio. Wayland broke after updating my kernel from 6.5.0~45 to 6.8.0. It uses X11 now
It seem to select X11 from the start like you can see in the logs below. I can't find any error related to Wayland in the gnome logs.
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: seat id: seat0
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: supported session types: x11
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: session type: x11
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: supported session types: (null)
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: local: yes
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: allow timed login: yes
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: initial: no
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: session class: greeter
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: seat id: (null)
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: id: (null)
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: Adding display on seat seat0
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: x11 login display for seat seat0 requested
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: New displays on seat0 will use x11
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: Getting session type (prefers xorg, falling back: no)
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: System supports graphics
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: udev has settled enough for graphics.
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: Found primary PCI graphics adapter, proceeding.
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: Checking if udev has settled enough to support graphics.
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: enumerating seats from logind
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: GdmManager: GDM starting to manage displays
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: Successfully connected to D-Bus
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: Changing user:group to gdm:gdm
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname gdm3[1739]: Gdm: Enabling debugging
Aug 19 13:16:48 hostname systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...

Wayland works with QXL. But QXL is very slow compared to Virtio. How to fix this or find the issue?
